# Display articles according to its specific taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I know that there is the same question but it didn't help me about my problem. 
I am working on a news/journal site right now. I want to display all articles/posts from same category on one page.

I've made my taxonomy like this (Same as my main navigation menu look like):

```
+News
  +Economy
  +Politics
  +Sports
  +Weather
  +Lifestyle
+...
  +...
  +...
  +...
  +...
+...
  +...
  +...
  +...
  +...
```

Now, when i try to enter Lifestyle (for example), I get 'page not found'. But if I type in the url something like: "mysite/taxonomy/term/87" I get all articles from Lifestyle category. I have created view for this but it is working only on categories that came with theme not for my categories that I created after. Do you have any suggestion?
Is there a way to change links form '/taxonomy/term/87' to '/news/lifestyle/ or there is a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal, we have option to generate custom URLs for category. When logged in, Go to:

Configuration -> search and metadata -> url aliases -> pattern

There go to Taxanomy term path section and set pattern for Vocabularies you have in your drupal website. In your case: set as

```
[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]
```

where [term:vocabulary] is 'news' and [term:name] is 'life style'

And whenever you create new vocabulary in drupal please make sure that you have checked checkbox '**use view override**' under view usage section.